# Not printing all the values of the field whereas field is having multiple values.How could I achieve this in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jira

I am running a jira jql and getting the Issue number like ABCD-1234 and passing it to the method in python script which is having below code
The JIRA issue in components Field is having multiple values .I am fetching those values in my python script but it is not printing all the values.It is printing only the first one

Can someone tell me how could I achieve this or am I missing something?

Values in Components Field of JIRA issue are in below way:
components = [A Cx,M px,R Last 1.2]

Below is the code in python method

```
for version in issue["fields"]["components"]:
       for val in version["name"]:
        print version["name"]
```

It's just printing the first one:

> A Cx

Below is the issue where I can see the component name associated with JIRA issue

https://test/rest/api/latest/issue/ABCD-1234

```
components":`
```

> [{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73063","id":"73063","name":"A
>   Cx"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73064","id":"73064","name":"M
>   Px"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73128","id":"73128","name":"R
>   test
>   4.5"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73065","id":"73065","name":"R
>   test 4.6"}]

`

After passing the issue I am getting this result

```
{
    u 'key': u 'NTPT-1', u 'fields': {
        u 'comment': {
            u 'total': 0,
            u 'startAt': 0,
            u 'maxResults': 0,
            u 'comments': []
        },
        u 'status': {
            u 'statusCategory': {
                u 'name': u 'Done',
                u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3',
                u 'id': 3,
                u 'key': u 'done',
                u 'colorName': u 'green'
            },
            u 'description': u 'The issue has been resolved and is awaiting verification.',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/status/5',
            u 'iconUrl': u 'https://test/images/icons/statuses/resolved.png',
            u 'id': u '5',
            u 'name': u 'Resolved'
        },
        u 'customfield_14101': None,
        u 'labels': [u 'regression', u 'triaged'],
        u 'customfield_11100': {
            u 'displayName': u 'Lal',
            u 'name': u 'ABCDEF',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/user?username=ABCDEF',
            u 'avatarUrls': {
                u '24x24': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '32x32': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '48x48': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '16x16': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513'
            },
            u 'emailAddress': u 'lal.test@abc.om',
            u 'key': u 'ABCDEF',
            u 'active': True,
            u 'timeZone': u 'GMT'
        },
        u 'fixVersions': [{
            u 'archived': False,
            u 'name': u 'ABC 5.0.4',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/version/98777',
            u 'released': False,
            u 'id': u '98777',
            u 'description': u 'Release iteration 5.0.4'
        }, {
            u 'archived': False,
            u 'name': u 'PTT 22.4.13',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/version/101081',
            u 'released': False,
            u 'id': u '101081',
            u 'description': u 'Release iteration 22.4.13'
        }],
        u 'summary': u 'testt1 of dod field',
        u 'assignee': {
            u 'displayName': u 'Lal',
            u 'name': u 'ABCDEF',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/user?username=ABCDEF',
            u 'avatarUrls': {
                u '24x24': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '32x32': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '48x48': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513',
                u '16x16': u 'https://test/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=ABCDEF&avatarId=48513'
            },
            u 'emailAddress': u 'lal.test@abc.om',
            u 'key': u 'ABCDEF',
            u 'active': True,
            u 'timeZone': u 'GMT'
        },
        u 'components': [{
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/component/73063',
            u 'id': u '73063',
            u 'name': u 'M Ax'
        }, {
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/component/73064',
            u 'id': u '73064',
            u 'name': u 'M kPx'
        }, {
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/component/73128',
            u 'id': u '73128',
            u 'name': u 'R Test 4.5'
        }, {
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/component/73065',
            u 'id': u '73065',
            u 'name': u 'R Test 4.6'
        }],
        u 'issuetype': {
            u 'name': u 'Defect',
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/issuetype/1',
            u 'iconUrl': u 'https://test/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31313&avatarType=issuetype',
            u 'subtask': False,
            u 'avatarId': 31313,
            u 'id': u '1',
            u 'description': u 'A problem which impairs or prevents the functions or performance of the product or its related artifacts. It can be related to software, hardware or both.'
        },
        u 'resolution': {
            u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/2/resolution/1',
            u 'id': u '1',
            u 'name': u 'Fixed',
            u 'description': u 'A fix for this issue has been implemented and is now working.'
        }
    }, u 'self': u 'https://test/rest/api/latestt/issue/1860256', u 'id': u '1860256', u 'expand': u 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you iterating over values in the version object? I suspect you want your code to look like

```
for component in issue["fields"]["components"]:
   print component["name"]
```

Comment: Even using the above one I am getting only the first value of the component field of JIRA issue ABCD-1234 . Value is A Cx

Answer (score 1):

So, I built what I assume your dict looks like:

```
issue = {'fields':{'components':[{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73063","id":"73063","name":"A Cx"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73064","id":"73064","name":"M Px"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73128","id":"73128","name":"R test 4.5"},{"self":"https://test/rest/api/2/component/73065","id":"73065","name":"R test 4.6"}],},}
```

And then wrote a basic loop to print each name:

```
for c in issue['fields']['components']:
  print(c['name'])
```

Which printed

```
A Cx
M Px
R test 4.5
R test 4.6
```

Comment: @ Aaron Lael I updated my question where I mentioned the result which I am getting after passing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Python debugging;

print the top level object

print issue["fields"]["components"]

Then do a loop

for component in issue["fields"]["components"]:
  print component

Then get into the fields of the objects in the loop

for component in issue["fields"]["components"]:
  print component[something or other]